# Law of Cosines for SSA triangles

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry

In most geometry courses, we learn that there's no such thing as "SSA Congruence". That is, if we have triangles $ABC$ and $DEF$ such that $AB = DE$, $BC = EF$, and $\angle A = \angle D$, then we cannot deduce that $ABC$ and $DEF$ are congruent.

However, there are a few special cases in which SSA "works". That is, suppose $ABC$ is a triangle. Let $AB = x$, $BC = y$, and $\angle A = \theta$. For some values of $x$, $y$, and $\theta$, we can uniquely determine the third side, $AC$.

(a) Use the Law of Cosines to derive a quadratic equation in $AC$.

(b) Use the quadratic polynomial you found in part (a) in order to find conditions on $x, y,$ and $\theta$ which guarantee that the side $AC$ is uniquely determined.

I have the quadratic equation in part A, letting z = AC I got $z^2-2xz\cos(\theta)+(x^2-y^2)=0$

What would I do for part B?

Thanks

Comment: $z^2-2xz\cos(\theta)+(x^2-y^2)=0\iff z=x\cos(\theta)\pm\sqrt{x^2\cos^2(\theta)-x^2+y^2}>0$ , then obtaining conditions when either sign of $\pm$ is possible?

Comment: there's a unique solution for $z$ iff the discriminant is zero...

Comment: I think the answer here is explained in a simple way by the picture that shows the ambiguity in the SSA case. Basically, if the given angle is not acute, then there are either one or zero solutions, otherwise there are either two or zero solutions. I think this can be straightforwardly proven from the law of sines, but I imagine it would work with the law of cosines as well.

Comment: @Ian is correct that non-ambiguity is assured if and only if the angle $\theta$ is non-acute. The geometry makes this clear, but to follow OP's algebraic line of reasoning, simply notice in Alexey's formula for $z$: iff $\theta$ is non-acute, thenn $x \cos\theta \leq 0$; since (presumably) $z>0$, this leaves no choice but to take the "$\pm$" to be "$+$". (This being so, I tend to advocate "SSnA" (Side-Side-non-Acute) as a congruence pattern; or, since the right-angle case usually gets its own name, "HL" (Hypotenuse-Leg), we could use "SSO" (Side-Side-Obtuse).)

Comment: @Rohini Sharma, you may like to join here we are bunch of indians, discussing math questions and joke around. 
http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/23760/we-love-math-physics-chemistry-and-random-talk