# I need help with an already asked question about "SSA congruence"

Tags: algebra-precalculus

In most geometry courses, we learn that there's no such thing as "SSA Congruence". That is, if we have triangles ABC and DEF such that AB=DE,BC=EF, and ∠A=∠D, then we cannot deduce that ABC and DEF are congruent.

However, there are a few special cases in which SSA "works". That is, suppose ABC is a triangle. Let AB=x, BC=y, and ∠A=θ. For some values of x, y, and θ, we can uniquely determine the third side, AC.

(a) Use the Law of Cosines to derive a quadratic equation in AC.

(b) Use the quadratic polynomial you found in part (a) in order to find conditions on x,y, and θ which guarantee that the side AC is uniquely determined.

I have the quadratic equation in part A, letting z = AC I got z^2−2xzcos(θ)+(x2−y2)=0

What would I do for part B?
I did read up on some of the articles already here, but I need an exact answer.
Someone said it could be proved with law of sines.   How?
Thanks so much and sorry for the hassle!

Comment: is this for a precalculus course

Comment: @dxiv, I think what's needed here may be a unique positive root.

Comment: @GerryMyerson You are right, thanks. I misread the figure, previous comment removed.

Comment: FWIW the question is a copy/paste of [Law of Cosines for SSA triangles](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1290295/law-of-cosines-for-ssa-triangles) minus the MathJax formatting.

Answer (score 1):

The following assumes that $\,x,y \gt 0\,$ and $\,0 \lt \theta \lt \pi\,$.

> I have the quadratic equation in part **A**, letting $\,z = AC\,$ I got $\;z^2-2xz\cos \theta + x^2-y^2=0$

The reduced discriminant of the quadratic in $\,z\,$ is $\,\frac{1}{4}\Delta=x^2 \cos^2\theta-x^2+y^2=y^2 - x^2 \sin^2\theta\,$.

- If $\,\Delta \lt 0 \iff y \lt x \sin\theta\,$ then the equation has no real roots. Geometrically, this is the case when $\,y\,$ is smaller than the distance from $\,B\,$ to the line $\,\mathbf{L}\,$ through $\,A\,$ at angle $\,\theta\,$ with $\,AB\,$.
- If $\,\Delta = 0 \iff y = x \sin\theta\,$ then the equation has the unique real root $\,z=\cos \theta\,$. The root is positive iff $\,\cos\theta \gt 0 \iff \theta \lt \pi / 2\,$. Geometrically, this is the case when $\,\theta\,$ is an acute angle and $\,\triangle ABC\,$ is a right triangle at $\,B\,$.
- If $\,\Delta \gt 0 \iff y \gt x \sin\theta\,$ then the equation has two real roots.

  - If the constant term is negative $\,x^2 - y^2 \lt 0 \iff y \gt x\,$ the two roots have opposite signs, so there is a unique positive root. Geometrically, this is the case when the circle of radius $\,y\,$ centered at $\,B\,$ intersects line $\,\mathbf{L}\,$ at two points on opposite sides of $\,A\,$, so that one of the points will correspond to $\,\theta\,$ (and the other one to $\pi - \theta\,$).
  - If $\,y = x\,$ then one root is $\,0\,$ which is not a valid side length, and the non-zero root is positive iff $\,\cos\theta \gt 0 \iff \theta \lt \pi / 2\,$. Geometrically, this is the case when $\,\theta\,$ is an acute angle, and $\,\triangle ABC\,$ is isosceles at $\,B\,$.
  - If $\,y \lt x\,$ then the two roots have the same sign, and are positive iff $\,\cos\theta \gt 0\,$. Geometrically, this is the case when the circle of radius $\,y\,$ centered at $\,B\,$ intersects line $\,\mathbf{L}\,$ at two points on the same side of $\,A\,$, forming two triangles with an acute angle at $\,A\,$.

In conclusion, there is a unique solution $\,z\,$ iff either $\,y \gt x\,$, or $\,0 \lt \theta \lt \pi/2\,$ and $\,y \in \{x, x \sin \theta\}\,$.

Comment: Why do I need the reduced discriminant of the quadratic?

Comment: The equation in $z$ (copied from the posted question) is a quadratic equation. The discriminant tells you if and how many real roots the equation has, as explained in some detail in the answer. `where did the triangle come from` It's the same triangle $\triangle ABC$ used in the question, with sides $x,y,z$ and $\angle A = \theta$.